# How do I compare an element to every element that comes after it in an array?

Tags: java

This is what I have so far, converted being the array, the value cannot be compared to 0 so its restricted in the if statement, my output is still incorrect.

```
    for(int i = 0; i < converted.length; i++) 
    {
        
        for(int x = i+1; x < converted.length; x++) 
        {
            
            if(converted[i] != 0 && converted[i] > converted[x] ) 
            {
                
                outOrder++;
                
                
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(outOrder);
```

Comment: please give a sample input and output that helps us to understand the question better

Comment: Why are you trying to compare them? Are you trying to sort them?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: A sample input for the array would be int converted = {182043765}; and the output should be 10, where each element is compared to all the elements ahead of it to see if its greater than it or not. using my code the output for the array is 13 which is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Given the explanation in the comments, the problem is that both elements should be tested for zero, not just the first:

```
if(converted[i] != 0 && converted[x] != 0 && converted[i] > converted[x] )
                  // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ Added
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, it works now. :)

Comment: if it works, mark the answer as accepted.